# How to build the psa-arch-tests with the cmake and armclang in the cygwin?

Tags: cmake

After Installing several softwares for building the compilation environment according to the Software Requirements Document which is in the "https://github.com/ARM-software/psa-arch-tests/blob/master/api-tests/docs/sw_requirements.md", when I compiled the source code psa-arch-tests of PSA API compliance test suite, the cygwin prompted the following error result:

```
luofeng66ok@DESKTOP ~/TFMB/psa-arch-tests/api-tests/build
$ cmake ../ -G"Unix Makefiles" -DTOOLCHAIN=ARMCLANG -DTARGET=tgt_dev_apis_tfm_an521 -DCPU_ARCH=armv8m_ml -DSUITE=CRYPTO -DPSA_INCLUDE_PATHS="/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/anpengfei/TFMB/trusted-firmware-m/interface/include/psa/crypto.h"
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/cygwin64/home/luofeng66ok/TFMB/psa-arch-tests/api-tests/BUILD/CMakeF
iles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/cygwin64/home/luofeng66ok/TFMB/psa-arch-tests/api-tests/BUILD/CMakeF
iles/CMakeError.log".
```

How to resolve this error?

`CMakeError.log` contains:

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: C:/cygwin64/bin/cc 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
拒绝访问。


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: C:/cygwin64/bin/cc 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
拒绝访问。
......
```

My installed software are:

- Host Operating System: Windows 10 64bit
- Scripting tools:

  ```
  luofeng66ok@DESKTOP-STB70QG ~/TFMB/psa-arch-tests/api-tests/build
  $ Python --version
  Python 3.7.0
  ```
- Cross Compiler toolchain :

  ```
  luofeng66ok@DESKTOP-STB70QG ~/TFMB/psa-arch-tests/api-tests/build
  $ armclang --version
  Product: MDK Plus 5.29
  Component: ARM Compiler 6.13.1
  Tool: armclang [5d895d00]
  Target: unspecified-arm-none-unspecified
  ```
- Build tools :

  ```
  luofeng66ok@DESKTOP-STB70QG ~/TFMB/psa-arch-tests/api-tests/build
  $ cmake --version
  cmake version 3.10.0-rc1
  CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).

  $ cygcheck --version
  cygcheck (cygwin) 3.1.4
  ```

and I have imported Arm Compiler in my environment variable,

[image]

At the same time, I also imported Arm Compiler by this way:

`C:\cygwin64\home\luofeng66ok\.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=/cygdrive/c/Keil/ARM/ARMCLANG/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/cygdrive/c/cmake/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/cygdrive/c/armgcc/bin:$PATH
```

My steps for building psa-arch-tests are:

```
 git clone https://github.com/ARM-software/psa-arch-tests.git

 git clone https://github.com/laurencelundblade/QCBOR.git (I do not why do this)

 cd <TF-M base folder>
 git clone https://git.trustedfirmware.org/trusted-firmware-m.git
 git clone https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-crypto.git -b mbedcrypto-3.0.1
 git clone https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5.git -b 5.5.0
 git-lfs
```

My directory `tfmb` contains:

```
luofeng66ok@DESKTOP-STB70QG ~/tfmb
$ ls
CMSIS_5  mbed-crypto  psa-arch-tests  trusted-firmware-m
```

Start compiling psa-arch-tests

```
cd api-tests
    mkdir BUILD
    cd  BUILD
    cmake ../ -G"Unix Makefiles" -DTOOLCHAIN=ARMCLANG -DTARGET=tgt_dev_apis_tfm_an521 -DCPU_ARCH=armv8m_ml -DSUITE=CRYPTO -DPSA_INCLUDE_PATHS="/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/anpengfei/TFMB/trusted-firmware-m/interface/include/psa/crypto.h"
```

as the errors above shows in my cygwin, I do not why?

```
luofeng66ok@DESKTOP-STB70QG ~/TFMB/psa-arch-tests/api-tests/build
$ cmake ../ -G"Unix Makefiles" -DTOOLCHAIN=ARMCLANG -DTARGET=tgt_dev_apis_tfm_an521 -DCPU_ARCH=armv8m_ml -DSUITE=CRYPTO -DPSA_INCLUDE_PATHS="/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/anpengfei/TFMB/trusted-firmware-m/interface/include/psa/crypto.h"
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/cygwin64/home/luofeng66ok/TFMB/psa-arch-tests/api-tests/BUILD/CMakeF
iles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/cygwin64/home/luofeng66ok/TFMB/psa-arch-tests/api-tests/BUILD/CMakeF
iles/CMakeError.log".
```